# YQL column projection using XPATH

Tags: yql

This query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM html 
WHERE url='http://wwww.example.com' 
AND xpath='//tr[@height="20"]'
```

returns XML:

```
<results>
    <tr height="20">
        <td height="20" width="425">
            <p>Institution 0</p>
        </td>
        <td width="134">
            <p>Minneapolis</p>
        </td>
        <td width="64">
            <p>MN</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</results>
```

Questions:

- Is there a way to use XPATH to create individual columns?
- Is there a way to create column aliases?

Example (invalid syntax):

```
SELECT td[position()=1]/p/. AS name, td[position()=2]/p/. AS city, td[position()=3]/p/. AS region
FROM   ...
```

Goal:

```
<results>
    <tr height="20">
      <name>Institution 0</name>
      <city>Minneapolis</city>
      <region>MN</region>
    </tr>
    ...
</results>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with XPath, as you are trying to do.  However one can apply [XSL Transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) to XML/HTML documents with YQL. Here's an example:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rows>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::tr" />
        </rows>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//tr">
        <row>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="td[1]/p" />
            </name>
            <city>
                <xsl:value-of select="td[2]/p" />
            </city>
            <region>
                <xsl:value-of select="td[3]/p" />
            </region>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr height="20">
                <td height="20" width="425">
                    <p>Institution 0</p>
                </td>
                <td width="134">
                    <p>Minneapolis</p>
                </td>
                <td width="64">
                    <p>MN</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20">
                <td height="20" width="425">
                    <p>Institution 1111</p>
                </td>
                <td width="134">
                    <p>Minneapolis 1111</p>
                </td>
                <td width="64">
                    <p>MN 11111</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**YQL query**

```
select * from xslt where stylesheet="url/to.xsl" and url="url/to.html"
```

**YQL Result**

```
<results>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <name>Institution 0</name>
            <city>Minneapolis</city>
            <region>MN</region>
        </row>
        <row>
            <name>Institution 1111</name>
            <city>Minneapolis 1111</city>
            <region>MN 11111</region>
        </row>
    </rows>
</results>
```

» [See an example running in the YQL console.](http://y.ahoo.it/ehB1g)

Comment: Great idea!  I wish I had seen this in the documentation.  Have an upvote, too.

Comment: Should I not also be able to add an `xpath` filter to the YQL query?  For example `AND xpath='//tr[@height="20"]'`?

Comment: There is no `xpath` parameter for the `xslt` table.