# How to get html as xml for XSLT conversion usage?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, yql

I would like to do some XSLT conversion with the HTML page with YQL. The following line is used to get HTML:

```
select * from html where url="http://example.com/somepage" and
      xpath='//div[@class="article-text"]'
```

How can I apply `select * from xslt where ...` to the previous result?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as I haven't used YQL before, but I guess you have to go the other way round: using XSLT to get the result out of the HTML and than apply the YQL-Query to get the XML as result:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//div[@class='article-text']" />
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="div[@class='article-text']">
   <articletext>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </articletext>
</xsl:template>
```

YQL query:

```
select * from xslt where stylesheet="url/name-of.xsl" and 
url="http://example.com/somepage"
```

This should result in

```
<results>
   <articletext>Text of article</articletext>
</results>
```

As I don't know YQL but was used working with XSLT/XPath, I just googled about it and found this recommendable SO example: [YQL column projection using XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449548/yql-column-projection-using-xpath) . Instead of just pasting the link I adjusted the XSLT-Part of the example provided there to match your query.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading the same SO recommendation - it doesn't work in my case since my `http://example.com/somepage` returns html, not xml and I get `failed to process feed and stylesheet: Invalid XML document` error.

Answer (score -1):

Note that HTML is not an XML-based language (though XHTML is). If you want to operate on HTML using XML tools, you will need to either find an HTML parser (such as [nekohtml](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/), which is based on Apache Xerces) or preconvert the HTML to XHTML using something like the W3C's [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) tool.

Comment: If I do the first query with YQL (http://goo.gl/sqwYhQ), then XML returned (http://goo.gl/eMpzeO). So, the question is about right YQL syntax to use what I've got with `select * from xslt`.